# Empty storyboard after downloading Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8

I had a storyboard in Xcode 7.3.1 that was set to Compact width and Regular height. When I downloaded the Xcode 8 beta and opened my storyboard file, I get an error: `Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and attach "/var/folders/xl/2m4k1hnj70bbc2dz94sbl029pc_hk8/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2016-06-17_10-28-34_051000".` I'm also unable to see anything on my storyboard.

Bug? I set the view to iPhone 6s.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can log a bug report at `https://bugreport.apple.com` without being a paid user. Please log the bug report as requested - it is a very simple process.

Answer (score 0):

When people default to editing a storyboard in Compact-Regular (which has always been strongly discouraged) their views and constraints get added only for that very specific configuration, and don't apply to other size classes. If this is the case for your document, one option is to use the File inspector to uncheck "Use Trait Collections" (prior to Xcode 8, it's "Use Size Classes") and choose to keep the data for iPhone. Then re-check the box.

Please do file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com, you only need to be a *registered* developer, but registering is free. The IB team can investigate what's going in with your project. Attaching the diagnostics folder mentioned in the warning will help provide the detail needed to diagnose the bug.